# Storing a circle from a lat/lng coordinates with a radius in MySQL

Tags: mysql, coordinates, spatial

I'm experimenting with polygons with MySQL, for now I investigated storing polygons.

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON((51.486941636341456 -0.06694793701171875,51.52241608253253 0.0164794921875,51.47796179607124 0.01750946044921875,51.486941636341456 -0.06694793701171875))'

INSERT INTO 'zones' ('polygon') VALUES (PolyFromText(@g));
```

However, I would like to insert circular shape with a specific radius in kilometres, knowing the center point is lat/lng coordinates. How is this method approached, with circles with a radius?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have a circle primitive, and creating a polygon to approximate a circle isn't trivial, especially near the poles.  Can you get away with storing your center point and a radius?